# Синтаксис. Роль слов в предложении

Tags: синтаксис

**Одна тропка пошла влево, а другая — прямо в лес**. (Арс.)
В этом предложении сказуемым будет являться ***пошла влево*** или просто ***пошла***?

И ещё вопрос: когда пропускается существительное при местоимении, порядковом числительном, прилагательном, причастии, то они уже выполняют функцию дополнения и подлежащего?
Например: ***Одна*** девочка любит читать классические книги, **другая** — современные.
***Другая*** будет выполнять роль подлежащего?

И вот ещё пример: *Гулкий и быстрый выстрел ударил в темноте. За ним — второй, третий.* (Пришв.)
***Второй, третий*** будут определениями или подлежащими?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна тропка пошла влево, а другая — прямо в лес. (Арс.)В этом предложении "влево" обстоятельство.

Одна девочка любит читать классические книги, другая — современные. В этом примере наблюдается разрыв синтаксических связей. Слово "другая" указывает на пропуск подлежащего "девочка".

> Ср.:  **Одна девочка** любит читать классические книги, **другая девочка** любит читать современные.
>
> Гулкий и быстрый выстрел ударил в темноте. За ним — второй, третий. (Пришв.) 
>   И в этом примере тоже: слова **"второй", "третий"** указывают на пропуск подлежащего "выстрел".
>
> Ср.: Гулкий и быстрый выстрел ударил в темноте. За ним — **второй,третий выстрел ударил.**

Ср. другие предложения.

**Южные ветры приносят нам тепло. Северные – холод.** Во втором предложении наблюдается разрыв синтаксических связей. **Слово «северные» указывает на пропуск подлежащего «ветры», аналогично дополнение «холод» указывает на пропуск сказуемого «приносят».** Так как второстепенные члены всегда крепятся к главным. Наличие определение всегда требует при себе определяемого слова, наличие прямого объекта – глагола-сказуемого. Таким образом, нарушение цепочки связей является сигналом неполноты, что и отражается в определении.

Подробнее вы можете ознокомиться здесь: [Неполные предложения](https://studopedia.ru/1_114621_lektsiya--nepolnie-predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию!